# How to hide only the closing tag of a div

Tags: html, css, tags

I need to hide a

```
</div>
```

without JavaScript or Jquery. I tried

```
<span style="display: none;"></div></span>
```

but it didn’t work at all.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
Thanks for confirming that it is NOT possible!
That’s what I wanted to know.

I solved my problem by changing my markup a little bit.
In my case it would have been logic because it simply would have saved some lines of code. (Basically I wanted to insert a div into another when a user activates an option, hiding just one closing tag and one new div opening tag when the option is disabled, showing them when the option is activated. It’s a tumblr theme with some closing tags rendered in {block:Posts} after every post. No need to get further in detail, i think it would be unnecessary complicated because the problem is already solved. Thanks!

Comment: did you mean that you want to hide a `<div/>` (an empty div), or did you really mean `</div>` (the "close an existing div" tag?

Comment: maybe you should tell us the problem you are trying to solve with hiding the closing div tag

Comment: @Pasha Zavoiskikh You’re right, I should tell you more about the context. I’m busy right now, but I’ll try to explain it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of absolutely no logical reason for doing this. even though a div tag may look like two elements to some, it is in fact one element and neither the starting nor the closing tag function on their own.

Comment: I have the same question. The reason is: I want to add `</div><div class="row">` in between divs, *if* it's a certain width.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that a

```
 </div>
```

tag is being displayed suggests that you have an extra closing tag - there is no corresponding

```
<div>
```

opening tag. These tags should never be displayed on a page if implemented correctly.
Try looking through your code and checking every opening

```
<div>
```

has a corresponding

```
</div>
```

In html all tags must be in pairs, having one opening and one closing tag. e.g.

```
<div id "test">
Test text!
</div>
```

JP

Comment: Thanks @J M but that was not my problem. I learned this like ten years before, but it might be very useful for others.